# Write text in the selected areas

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, textblock

I have this wpf code.

```
<TextBlock Name="TB" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="das   asd     asdasd  asd asd as d as   2323213      123123" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
```

I need to write a text in one of these red areas.

[image]

At the same time I need to specify the position of the text like this:

```
    TB.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text="123", ContentX = 4, ContetLine= 1});
    TB.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text="B", ContentX = 6, ContentLine= 2});
    TB.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text="55555", ContentX = 7, ContentLine= 4});
```

Text may be added by using Inlines with custom text color and style.

And i dont know font size and where text will be wrapped.

**Edit 1**:

The text can be different.

Chars may be styled (color, font size, text style).

I need something like full array of chars and pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions maybe? (using System.Text.RegularExpressions)
To find the first space the code would be:

```
  [a-z]+
```

You would just count the found characters then and cut the string.